# Android ShapeDrawable different colors

Tags: android, xml

sorry for my bad english :)

I need create other buttons like first of them.
https://scontent-b-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/v/577464_192010300985304_317054198_n.jpg?oh=bf0e536e576de63acf060604109797b0&oe=52777780

I created file shape_style.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#33B5E5" />

    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

and second shape_style_2.xml with only different color

so I need do this for other buttons,but I don't want create 10 files with only different color

my layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <View
            android:background="@drawable/shape_style"
            style="@style/button_home_view" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/button_home_textview"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_style_2"
            android:text="@string/button_1" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

it is some better way to solved this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Unlike other components, drawable resources are not given IDs like other widgets or color. They are referenced by filename, i.e. through R.drawable. 
They must be handled in separate files.

See this documentation for more clarity - [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)